# How did ancient Dravidians tell the time?

Tags: time-keeping, ancient-india

Before the invention of clocks people used devices such as sundials, sandclock etc to know the time. Wikipedia gives you the measurements once used by south Indians (time,area, weight). My doubt is what is the ancient thamizh people used to know time. Are there any references stating they used devices to know time.

Comment: It would be nice if you provided a link to "thamiz" - google produces only a reference to a movie.  I infer that the Thamiz are an ancient Dravidian people, but someone might be able to answer the question if the connections were explicit.

Comment: Yes, they are the dravidians. Thamizh is a language commonly known as Tamil in english. It is pronounced as 'Thamizh' not as 'Tamil'.

Comment: For what purpose? Dawn, noon and sunset are trivial. Mid morning and mid afternoon are not much more difficult. Why would it be necessary to know the time more accurately than that in an ancient civilization, when that actually suffices for most agricultural workers today, most of the time?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The Wikipedia article the OP described has units of time that are more accurate then Dawn, noon and sunset. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_units_of_measurement#Units_of_time_in_ancient_Tamil_history

Comment: @KolappanNathan: (1) Those are all '*time intervals*', not '*times of day*'. World of difference. (2) Healthy resting heartbeat is (***not*** coincidently) very close to 60 beats / minute, making the measurement of *time intervals* in units of a second quite straightforward far into pre-history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tamul and Telugu both used the same system of time keeping, which was derived from ancient Hindi methods and was based on a 60-hour day, the word "ghurry" meaning an hour (24-minute period):

[image: Telugu time keeping]

The standard method of time keeping was the water clock which was used by the Hindus and other peoples of India for thousands of years going back. The water clock was known as the "ghurry al" and was typically made of copper, brass or gold. The ancient Hindu water clock is known explicitly from a detailed description by [Lalla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lalla), the famous 8th century Indian astronomer (qv).

Comment: you mean Hindu methods or Hindi methods in second line?